# For loop to repeat 20 times in sql statement

Tags: mysql

I am using below but getting error, what is wrong in this code    :

```
declare  
begin  
for i in 1..20  
loop  
execute immediate 'update table IMP_BACKUP set name='XYZ' where status='INVALID'';  
end loop;  
end;  
/
```

Comment: So what error are you getting?You might be missing something after declare.

Comment: Why would you execute that SQL statement 20 times?  The first execution ought to do it.

Comment: Hi Robert , In this logic we want to execute 20times or n number of times if this .. It is requirement ..

Comment: Don't think about sql ..please treat it as if name is between A or N or something like that .. then change the status .. my main concern is how to execute the sql in for loop ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare variable i as

```
declare
  i number(2);
begin
for i in 1..20 loop 
  execute immediate 'update table IMP_BACKUP set name=''XYZ'' where   status=''INVALID''';  
end loop;  
end;  
/
```

Comment: Now it executed   .. although I have issue   
ORA-06550: line 5, column 19:
PLS-00114: identifier 'update table IMP_BACKUP' too long

Comment: @user2500742 why do u need to use *execute immediate*

Comment: I saw some reference for that .. update table IMP_BACKUP set name='XYZ' where status='INVALID'  .. needs to be after execute immediate  .. I have tried without execute also .. but no luck

Comment: Thanks a lot . I appreciate it . It perfectly worked for me this time .Thanks again